# Mesh disapear when camera close

Tags: 3d, three.js

I load a gltf scene to three.js, but when i move the camera near to the object,some meshes are disappear
Left is the object when the camera takes a distance, right is when i move the camera closer

[image]

my source code for gltf loader

```
function LoadModel( scene ) {
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader(); 
loader.load(
  "./gltf/girl.gltf",
  function (gltf) {

    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    var hemispheric = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x222222, 1.2);
    scene.add(hemispheric);
  });
}
```

my repo https://github.com/giangm9/hacc/tree/master/src/3d

Comment: This might be a problem with bounding boxes not being calculated...

Can you try doing a scene.traverse( (o)=>{ if(o.geometry) o.geometry.calculateBoundingBox() } )

aftter you load and see if that changes the behavior?

Comment: following the link https://discourse.threejs.org/t/mesh-disapear-when-camera-close/2914/2
i fixed with 
    scene.traverse( function( object ) {

        object.frustumCulled = false;

    } );

Comment: What you are describing is still a symptom of missing or incorrect bounding boxes.. This happens with animated characters a lot since bounding boxes for the bind pose don't cover where the actual animated character will be... but if you don't mind not having frustum culling, then your solution is fine :) If you want frustum culling, look into setting boundingBox and boundingSphere manually to a box big enough to cover the whole animated character.